# NodeJS running a promise-mysql query inside a foreach loop waiting for result each time

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

I am trying to query a mysql database twice, the second time, multiple times for each result from the first time but I am unable to work out how to wait for the result from the second query before continuing the

```
 admin.get('/', function (req, res) {
        mysqlQ("SELECT I.ID as ID, C.ID AS CID, I.PD AS PostDate, C.Name AS CatName, U.UserName AS UserName, I.Title AS Title, I.Post AS PostData FROM categories AS C JOIN INAT AS I ON C.ID = I.Category JOIN Users AS U on U.ID = I.User").then(function (INAT) {
        INAT.forEach(function (team) {
            team.time = moment(team.PostDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
            team.TS = moment(team.time, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
            mysqlQ("SELECT I.ID AS InatID, J.Name AS JobTitle, C.Name AS Category FROM `Jobs` AS J JOIN Jobs2INAT AS J2I ON J.ID = J2I.JobsID JOIN INAT AS I ON I.ID = J2I.INATID JOIN categories AS C on C.ID = J.Categories WHERE I.ID = " + team.ID).then(function (jobs) {
                    team.jobs = jobs;
                });
        });
        var context = {
            INAT: INAT
        };
        var homeTemplate = pug.compileFile(__dirname + '/templates/home.pug');
        var html = homeTemplate(context);
        res.send(html);
    });
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) - while this code is NodeJS and not AJAX, the same principle applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to create a second promise that will resolve once **all** your secondary queries have returned, building a second promise with `when.all()` or `bluebird.all` (or their equivalent `*.map`)

You are also trying to modify the entries in your `INAT` object but to do so you too need to wait for your secondaries promise to resolve before updating `INAT` and sending your final result.

There are many way to do that but something like this should work

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'); // or use any other Promise library

admin.get('/', function (req, res) {
    mysqlQ("SELECT I.ID as ID, C.ID AS CID, I.PD AS PostDate, C.Name AS CatName, U.UserName AS UserName, I.Title AS Title, I.Post AS PostData FROM categories AS C JOIN INAT AS I ON C.ID = I.Category JOIN Users AS U on U.ID = I.User")
        .then(function (INAT) {
            var promiseArray = [];
            promiseArray.push(Promise.resolve(INAT));
                // For each INAT entry create a new Promise that will resolve with your job
                INAT.forEach(function (team) {
                    team.time = moment(team.PostDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                    team.TS = moment(team.time, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
                    promiseArray.push(
                        mysqlQ("SELECT I.ID AS InatID, J.Name AS JobTitle, C.Name AS Category FROM `Jobs` AS J JOIN Jobs2INAT AS J2I ON J.ID = J2I.JobsID JOIN INAT AS I ON I.ID = J2I.INATID JOIN categories AS C on C.ID = J.Categories WHERE I.ID = " + team.ID)
                    );
                });

            return Promise.all(promiseArray);
        }).then(function(results) {
            // Add the looked-up jobs to INAT
            var [INAT, ...jobs] = results;
            INAT.forEach(function(team, i) {
                team.jobs = jobs[i];
            })

            // Send your answer
            var context = {
                        INAT: INAT
            };
            var homeTemplate = pug.compileFile(__dirname + '/templates/home.pug');
            var html = homeTemplate(context);
            return res.send(html);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // do some error handling
            return res.send("Unable to process / => err = "+err);
        })
    })
```

PS : don't forget to end all your `.then(function() {})` with a `return` statement

Comment: Thanks that got it, and really helped me understand promises!

Comment: @bertie.io I have applied your edit, that according to me was incorrectly declined by the edit review queue, if Boris like to rollback he is free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this, you are trying to assign your variable before the 2nd promise resolves.

If you are waiting for 2 promises to return, the final action needs to be executed after the last promise resolves

```
 admin.get('/', function (req, res) {
    mysqlQ("SELECT I.ID as ID, C.ID AS CID, I.PD AS PostDate, C.Name AS CatName, U.UserName AS UserName, I.Title AS Title, I.Post AS PostData FROM categories AS C JOIN INAT AS I ON C.ID = I.Category JOIN Users AS U on U.ID = I.User").then(function (INAT) {
    INAT.forEach(function (team) {
        team.time = moment(team.PostDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        team.TS = moment(team.time, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
        mysqlQ("SELECT I.ID AS InatID, J.Name AS JobTitle, C.Name AS Category FROM `Jobs` AS J JOIN Jobs2INAT AS J2I ON J.ID = J2I.JobsID JOIN INAT AS I ON I.ID = J2I.INATID JOIN categories AS C on C.ID = J.Categories WHERE I.ID = " + team.ID).then(function (jobs) {
                team.jobs = jobs;

                //  *************<<<<<<<<<<<
                //  Any code that needs to wait for the second mysqlQ query needs to go here
                //  *************<<<<<<<<<<<
              var context = {
                  INAT: INAT
              };
              var homeTemplate = pug.compileFile(__dirname + '/templates/home.pug');
              var html = homeTemplate(context);


            });
    });
    res.send(html);
    // var context = {
    //     INAT: INAT
    // };
    // var homeTemplate = pug.compileFile(__dirname + '/templates/home.pug');
    // var html = homeTemplate(context);
    // res.send(html);
});
```

})

Something like the above would work, although still a bit hacky, and is probably frowned upon due to the "callback/promise hell" that JS developers are fond of.

Comment: That would cause the Express request to be send each time the foreach loop runs sending a request to the browser each time

Comment: @bertie.io you're right! edited my post to fix that. cannot send headers twice.